# Register schema for sqlalchemy query in python-eve

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, eve

I am attempting to create an endpoint for a query joining multiple tables.  registerSchema takes a sqlalchemy Base object.  The solution I came up with was to create a database view for the sql statement, and use the model to reference the view.

Is this supported more natively with a registered schema? I would rather not maintain database views dependencies in my migrations.

sql for the dataview(replaced the table names with contrived examples)

```
      CREATE VIEW v_user_offices AS
           SELECT b.id AS building_id,
                  b.name AS building_name,
                  o.id AS office_id,
                  o.name AS office_name,
                  uo.user_id AS user_id
           FROM buildings AS b
           INNER JOIN office_buildings AS ob
           ON ob.building_id=b.id
           INNER JOIN offices AS o
           ON o.id=ob.office_id
           INNER JOIN user_offices AS uo
           ON uo.office_id=o.id;
```

sqlalchemy Model:

```
class ViewUserOffices(CommonColumns):
    __tablename__ = 'v_user_offices'
    building_id = Column(Integer)
    building_name = Column(String)
    office_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    office_name = Column(String)
    user_id = Column(Integer)
```

settings.py

```
# The DOMAIN dict explains which resources will be available and how they will
# be accessible to the API consumer.
registerSchema('v_user_offices')(ViewUserOffices)
DOMAIN = {
    'user_offices': ViewUserOffices._eve_schema['v_user_offices']
    }

DOMAIN['user_offices'].update({
    'item_title': 'user_office',
    'item_lookup_field': 'user_id',
    'resource_methods': ['GET']
    })
```

Comment: I am currently looking for a way to use sqlalchemy inheritance to accomplish this - http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html , though my concern is there will be a limitation updating the records

Answer (score 0):

The sqlalchemy-eve plugin is trying to be as close to sqlalchemy declarative approach as possible. If you can define your models in sqlalchemy you should be able to register them in python-eve.

In your case IMHO the only reasonable approach is to create a view and declare it in sqlalchemy as you did.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can define this schema by taking advantage of [sqlalchemy relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html). If your UserOffices class has all of the correct relationships defined, then registerSchema should automagically take care of the relationships between associated objects. All you will have to do is set the `embedded` parameter in your requests if you would like to embed the associated objects in the response.

A View makes sense if you do not want your client to have to worry about declaring embedded objects.